# "Classic" in product name as prefix

Tags: word-order

I have an older version of a product named `Foo Classic` (where `Foo` is replaced with an actual proper name).

Would it sound/look weird if I rename it to `Classic Foo`, especially for a native speaker?

Comment: Maybe, but only slightly, because we're so used to the `Foo Classic`-type wording from brands. Some marketing person must have determined a long time ago that it's best to write the brand name first, before "Classic" or any other qualifier, even though in normal written English (absent marketing influences) it would definitely be described as "Classic Foo".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Nick. I'd happily accept it as an answer if you turn it into one.

Comment: You can name a product anything you want.  Could be *Archetypal Foo* if you wish.  Probably *Hackneyed Foo* would be a poor choice, though.

Comment: Altho' - as @HotLicks says - you can, in theory, "name a product anything you want", you also need to be aware of Trade Mark (TM) laws.  If there's a TM for "Foo Classic", the alternative "Classic Foo" might still be deemed to be an infringement of the TM - depending on national law & lots of other issues.

Comment: TrevorD, thanks for your comment. `Foo` in this case is the name of the main (newer version) product, so no TM conflict in this case.

Comment: Your Q says that you are just changing the word order!

Comment: Voting to close this Q as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Yes, the older one is currently called and sold as `Foo Classic`, and I'd like to rename it to `Classic Foo`.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You just said that "Foo" "is the name of the main (newer version)" - from which I understand you to mean the older version is NOT named "Foo". Yet now you say that "the older one **is currently called and sold as** Foo Classic".  Anyway, I've warned you of the risk of TM infringement, and it's up to you!!

Comment: TrevorD, I sell both `Foo` and `Foo Classic`, and would like to rename the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Classic Foo** might sound awkward, but only slightly, because we're so used to the **Foo Classic**-type wording from brands. (It also depends on your target audience -- see my "P.S." at the bottom of this answer.)

(Off the top of my head, I'm thinking about **Coca-Cola Classic**, **Pepsi Next**, and **Mountain Dew: Code Red**, all of which have the brand name followed by the adjective... I must have soft drinks on my mind.)

Some marketing person must have determined a long time ago that it's best to write the brand name first, before "Classic" or any other moodifier; this way you hear or read the brand name before anything else. This style of writing brand names has become so familiar that it sounds normal, even though in normal written English (absent marketing influences) the adjective would come first (it would be described as **Classic Foo** or **Code Red Mountain Dew** or **Next Pepsi**).

P.S.: I'm saying this as a native American English speaker who loves reading books but can't help but be immersed in the commercial culture of my country. This is my opinion, and other people might disagree. Your choice also might depend on your target market: if your customers are literary, educational, conservative, or upper-class types, maybe they'd prefer the slightly more formal-sounding **Classic Foo** over **Foo Classic**.